# Error everytime i do sudo apt update

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, ppa, ruby

every time i do apt update i got this error message

```
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/brightbox/ruby-ng/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

i already tried to do

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:brightbox/rubg-ng and still got problem
```

also already tried reinstalling and something similiar to ppa, launchpad,and ruby but i think i don't get the right package in this case. i also see the sources.list in apt folder, there is not something similiar to ppa, launchpad,and ruby

Comment: Did you look at https://launchpad.net/~brightbox/+archive/ubuntu/ruby-ng as it clearly states it doesn't provide support for 22.04 or *jammy*.  PPA's are 3rd party sources don't forget (ie. your job to check if safe/useful for your system).  Your details are unclear though, as your paste shows 22.04 but you tagged 20.04?

Comment: i want to uninstall the packages, cause its installed automatic when i do something, but i dont know what is the package name

Comment: Your question details do not mention uninstalling packages; only an error on update (*updating software lists*) which will be corrected by removing that PPA which does **not** support any product after 2020-April (20.04); details on correcting that (ie. removing the bad source you've added) are in the duplicate I tagged.  You can use GUI tools if desktop, or command tools if server (*you didn't specify*)

Comment: i tried sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:brightbox/rubg-ng/ubuntu then i got
Unable to handle repository shortcut 'ppa:brightbox/rubg-ng/ubuntu'

Comment: Refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu (or the duplicate link).  Remove it using a text editor, or the GUI tools (if using a desktop).  By commenting out the line (*adding a # at the start of the line*) the source will be *disabled* and ignored; the GUI tools just add this "#" when you uncheck that inappropriate source you've added.  Where the source exists on your system will depend on how it was added.  (*Myself, I always use the text editor `vim` & leave comments on why added, date etc; and clues so I can `fgrep` search for my changes*)

Comment: It fixed now thank you so much for your help

Comment: how do i tell people if this case is solved

Comment: My first comment was generated by the web site when I *flagged* this question as a duplicate. It'll be marked as such when enough *close-voting* users of the site agree with my *flag*; you can I suspect help that, alas sorry I don't know how (*I've little experience asking questions on this site sorry*). Well done on solving it though.

Comment: FYI:  The directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` is also searched for sources..  that directory is *empty* on a new install, so anything in there was added by users with `sudo` privileges after install.